# Deploying Flask as CGI on shared web hosting

Tags: python, .htaccess, flask, cgi

I have small Flask app that I wish to deploy. I have bought domain name and hosting service on bigrock.com.
I wrote a small mock app to test whether my Flask app would work as CGi. 
I have used following configuration:

File :`/home/USERNAME/public_html/cgi-bin/cgi.cgi`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  

from wsgiref.handlers import CGIHandler
from myapp import app
import os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()

os.environ['SERVER_NAME'] = '127.0.0.1'
os.environ['SERVER_PORT'] = '5000'
os.environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'GET'
os.environ['PATH_INFO'] = ""
CGIHandler().run(app)
```

File :`/home/USERNAME/public_html/cgi-bin/myapp.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "This is Hello World!\n"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

File : `/home/USERNAME/public_html/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /home/USERNAME/public_html/cgi-bin/cgi.cgi/$1 [L]
```

Running cgi.cgi using ssh session as `./cgi.cgi`

gives following output:

```
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 21

This is Hello World!
```

Also running myapp.py as

> python myapp.py

activates the development server:

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

And now, no matter when I access my site anyway:

www.mysite.com

www.mysite.com/cgi.cgi

www.mysite.com/cgi-bin/cgi.cgi

I get a 500 internal server error.

When I used a Python hello world cgi script it worked perfectly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Content-Type: text/html"
print
print """\
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

I know similar questions have been brought up again and again but none has been properly answered or the answers don't seem to work.

Comment: Try using IP instead of 127.0.0.1 in cgi.cgi

Comment: Please go through [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/cgi/#creating-a-cgi-file)

Comment: No, using IP doesn't help either.

Comment: I have setup just according to Flask's CGI recommendation.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you also post the exception log from the 500 response. It should be in the httpd error log I assume.

Comment: error log on cpanel is empty.

Comment: I'll try to modify my cgi script to log error. any suggestions on that?

Comment: First take the Python helloworld, let it write something to os.stderr, and check that this message shows up in the error log. If you can't make that work, assign file("my_error_log","a") to os.stderr and try again.

Comment: Alternatively maybe you can activate flask debug mode for your site temporarily.

Answer (score -1):

After tweaking multiple things I finally got it to work.
Thanks guys.

I think this did the trick:
I uploaded all the files to /scgi-bin and edited .htaccess to reflect the same.

Comment: Please add your elaborate answer so that it can help posterity.